# In Eclipse automate search in specific file type

Tags: eclipse, macros, window, keyboard-shortcuts

in my working day I am constantly looking for texts in * .java files or * .xml files. To do this I select the text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and change the extension. These operations take me a little while.

Is there a shortcut or a macro to select the text and launch the search on the java, or on the xml or other types of files?
(like search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in a single file)

Comment: In _Search > Quick Search_ (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L), the field _in_ (with `*.java, *.xml` in your case) will be remembered. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I try it but It is very slow. I need a very fast search: select text and search (in a java or xml)

Comment: What makes you say _Quick Search_ is slow? If you need a fast search, use [InstaSearch](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch).